# changing slider value as List item value in flutter New version

Tags: flutter, dart

Yesterday i have ask question about this topic ,yesterday it was test project to understand the issue ,today i tried to apply what i learned on my app ,but i get small error i can't fix it.

I have this class file (viewdegree.dart):

```
class Digree {
  final int index;
  final String title_k;
  final String title_a;
  final String aya;
  final String link;
  final String activity_k;
  final String activity_a;
  String act_id;
  String mydigree;
  Digree(this.index, this.title_k, this.title_a, this.aya, this.link,
      this.activity_k, this.activity_a, this.act_id, this.mydigree);
}
```

I have this page which import above class ,the page send request to API to display some rows ,in each row i have slider to detect the degree for each item data.

when i change the slider value it send post request to server to add degree to the row or update it ,the i want to setstate the value of Slider to new degree.

the page code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:jiyanUquraan/classes/viewdigree.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';
class DisplayList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DisplayListState createState() => _DisplayListState();
}
TextEditingController insertedDegree = TextEditingController();
var video_link = '';

class _DisplayListState extends State<DisplayList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List digrees = [];
    var widthView = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    Map rdata = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    var did = int.parse(rdata['dayId'].toString());
    var u_id = rdata['userID'];
    var m_id = rdata['courseId'];
    int w_id;
    if (did <= 6) {
      w_id = 1;
    } else if (did <= 12) {
      w_id = 2;
    } else if (did <= 18) {
      w_id = 3;
    } else {
      w_id = 4;
    }
    Future<List> fetchDigrees() async {
      var url =
          'http://10.0.2.2/jiyan/test/api/activities/activiy_list.php?d_id=$did&m_id=$m_id&u_id=$u_id';

      var response = await http.get(url);

      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(data);
      for (var x in data) {
        Digree newdigree = Digree(
            x['index'],
            x['title_k'],
            x['title_a'],
            x['aya'],
            x['link'],
            x['activity_k'],
            x['activity_a'],
            x['act_id'],
            x['mydigree']);
        digrees.add(newdigree);
      }
      return digrees;
    }
// Insert Func
    send_degree(uId, actId, degree, w_id, did, m_id) async {
      var sendData = {
        'u_id': uId.toString(),
        'act_id': actId.toString(),
        'degree': degree.toString(),
        'm_id': m_id.toString(),
        'd_id': did.toString(),
        'w_id': w_id.toString()
      };
      var url = 'http://10.0.2.2/jiyan/test/api/data/changedata.php';
      var response = await http.post(url, body: sendData);
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (data.status) {
        print('OK');
      }
    }
// End of Insert Func
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchDigrees(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          Map rdata = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
          var lang = rdata['lang'];
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Center(
              child: Text("Loading"),
            );
          } else {
            YoutubePlayerController _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
                initialVideoId: snapshot.data[0].link,
                flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
                  autoPlay: false,
                  mute: false,
                ));
            return Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 20, 25, 20),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                      lang == 'k'
                          ? snapshot.data[0].title_k
                          : snapshot.data[0].title_a,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, color: Colors.white)),
                  //for top margin
                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                  // dexription
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    width: widthView,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                        color: const Color.fromRGBO(180, 80, 80, 0.3)),
                    child: Text(snapshot.data[0].aya,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 26, color: Colors.greenAccent[100])),
                  ),
                  // now populating your ListView for `Directionality`
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      // Start activities
                      Column(
                          children: snapshot.data.map<Widget>((item) {
                        double _value;
                        var xx = double.parse(item.mydigree);
                        if (xx > 0) {
                          _value = double.parse(item.mydigree);
                        } else {
                          _value = 0.0;
                        }

                        return Directionality(
                          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                    border: Border.all(
                                        width: 2, color: Colors.white),
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(230, 200, 200, 0.2)),
                                width: widthView,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
                                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 25, 0, 25),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(
                                      lang == 'k'
                                          ? item.activity_k
                                          : item.activity_a,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 28, color: Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 15,
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            boxShadow: [
                                              BoxShadow(
                                                color: Colors.yellow[200]
                                                    .withOpacity(0.2),
                                                spreadRadius: 2,
                                                blurRadius: 20,
                                              )
                                            ],
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                            color:
                                                Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),
                                        width: widthView,
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                        child: Slider(
                                          max: 100,
                                          min: 0,
                                          divisions: 20,
                                          value: _value,
                                          label: _value.round().toString(),
                                          onChanged: (val) {
                                            send_degree(u_id, item.act_id, val,
                                                w_id, did, m_id);
                                            setState(() {
                                              _value = val;
                                              item.mydigree = val.toString();
                                            });
                                          },
                                        ))
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      }).toList()),
                      // End activities
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Text('خەلەکا ئەڤرو',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26, color: Colors.yellow)),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      YoutubePlayer(
                        controller: _controller,
                        showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
                        progressIndicatorColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

When i change the slider value it is come back to zero and degree with zero value inserted on server as show on video.

```
https://streamable.com/0ejpel
```

How can i fixed it.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your variable is set value in build method, every time you call setState, your variable is set again and slider show default value again.

for solve this problem, you should set your variable out of the build method.

EDIT:

change your code like this:

```
List digrees = [];
  var widthView;
  Map rdata;
  var did;
  var u_id;
  var m_id;
  var w_id;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    widthView = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    rdata = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    did = int.parse(rdata['dayId'].toString());
    u_id = rdata['userID'];
    m_id = rdata['courseId'];
    w_id;
    if (did <= 6) {
      w_id = 1;
    } else if (did <= 12) {
      w_id = 2;
    } else if (did <= 18) {
      w_id = 3;
    } else {
      w_id = 4;
    }
  }

Future<List> fetchDigrees() async {
...
}

Future<void> send_degree(uId, actId, degree, w_id, did, m_id) async {
...
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// put your future builder here
}
```

and in slider onChange method:

```
send_degree(u_id, item.act_id, val,
    w_id, did, m_id).then((_){
      setState(() {
        _value = val;
      });
});
```

this is not the ideal solution and best code. but you can change it to be better.

Comment: thanks a lot ,I guess that the problem ,but that variable must get its value inside future builder ,how can i solve that